# Filter Dataframe by minute forp multiple days

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I have a dataframe with minute data spanning of multiple days and I would like to filter in such a way, that I get the following time from each day:
09:31

Is there an easy way to do this? I was thinking to to do something along the lines of slice(None) after separating the days and time into separate columns but I thought there might be a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `at_time()` is what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range("2019-08-01 00:00", "2019-08-11 00:00", freq="1min")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index), 3), index=index, columns=["a", "b", "c"])

df.at_time("09:31")
```

Comment: never knew about `at_time` :)

Comment: I am getting an error message: 
TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex, because I have a multi-index with level=0 being the date of this format: <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>

Comment: @Tartaglia, you can get the integer-location by `df.index.levels[0].indexer_at_time("09:31")`, then use `df.iloc[]` to get the rows.

Comment: Thanks, that is a nice approach. I was able to make this work also: df=df.unstack().at_time("09:31").stack()